# Launchpad Issue

Tags: macos, finder, macbook-pro, launchpad

So I was cleaning up my launchpad since Adobe installs a lot of minor applications and I wanted to have them all in one folder. Then I moved all of those Adobe applications to a new folder but the old folder won't go away. It's just an empty folder with nothing in it.

I have tried terminal commands, I have tried to hold in Alt and CTRL, I have done multiple restarts, putting things in the folder makes that item disappear and not show up unless I restart the whole dock. I have looked for a way to put a folder inside an another folder to hide it but that does not seem possible.

It annoys me but it does not bother me so much that I will do a re-install of Mavericks to make it go away. If there is no way to remove it, I will just have to live with it I guess.

I have researched this issue with no success. I have only encountered people with the same problem on OS X Lion and the way they fixed it, is not possible on Mavericks, since I tried.

This happened after the update to Mavericks 10.9.4.

My specs:

MacBook Air 13" (Late - 2013)

Mavericks 10.9.4

Comment: Are you referring to a folder that is visible in Launchpad, or a folder in `/Applications`? For the Launchpad folder, it should disappear once there is only one item remaining in the folder. It should turn into just the icon for that remaining application. As far as a folder in `/Applications` goes, you can safely delete that folder if it is now empty.

Comment: I am referring to a folder visible in Launchpad and yes it should go away with nothing in it, but it does not.

Comment: Try adding one or more items to the folder, then removing them again.

Comment: Doesn't work, the item disappears instead of going into the folder.

Comment: Can you try the steps listed here for me? https://discussions.apple.com/message/15941820

Comment: Only the first two commands, not the `sqlite3` one. You should be issuing `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db` and then `killall Dock` or reboot.

Comment: Maybe back up those `db` files first...

Comment: I have done those terminal commands and will now reboot, I will comment on how it went.

Comment: No success, I think I have a bad update or install of Mavericks. But I will live with it until the public beta of Yosemite, then I can do a clean install. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: No problem. I'll keep you posted if I find any other possible solutions...

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an item back to the empty folder that you can't delete.
2. Change the name of the folder to something else (doesn't matter what, just some random thing like "asd").
3. Take out the item you put in it.

After these steps, the folder should be gone automatically. I got this solution from the last answer below in this Apple discussions [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6641820).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give either of these apps a try - not exactly ideal to have to install a separate app to manage it but it doesn't seem that there is an easy way to modify the Launchpad DB. If either works you could always uninstall after.

> http://launchpadmanager.com/
>
> Has a pay version but seems the free version should do what you need.

Or

> http://horizon-nigh.org/launchpad-editor.html
>
> A bit more utilitarian but seems to be free as well.